# How can i draw a rectangle around a label control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added a label control to form1 designer and assign some text to it.
Then i did label mouse click event:

```
private void label5_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawRectangleOnLabel = true;
            label5.Invalidate();
        }
```

And the label paint event:

```
private void label5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DrawRectangleOnLabel == true)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, label5.Width, label5.Height);
            }
        }
```

But what i see when i click on the label is half rectangle only the Left and Top the right and bottom of the rectangle not exist/show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the rectangle is drawn with a pen width of `1` and the right and bottom portions fall outside the bounds of the label.  Just make it one pixel smaller :

```
 e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, label1.Width - 1, label1.Height - 1);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `ControlPaint` method instead :

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, label1.DisplayRectangle, 
                        Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

This gives you access to various other `ButtonBorderStyle`s (dashed, dotted, inset, outset).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `BorderStyle` property on `MouseClick` event. And assign single event for all labels.

```
label1.MouseClick += new EventHandler(this.AllLable_MouseClick);
label2.MouseClick += new EventHandler(this.AllLable_MouseClick);
label3.MouseClick += new EventHandler(this.AllLable_MouseClick);

private void AllLable_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    if (lbl.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
        lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    else
        lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
}
```

Comment: `BorderStyle` makes a black border.  If you want a different colour, you have to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple "box" just add a Forms.Panel and place your controls on it. Then set the Panel border to FixedSingle.